# Struggling with character encoding with ShinyApp

Tags: r, shiny, encode

I'm struggling with character encoding with my ShinyApp. I'm using ShinyProxy for deploying the apps.

I read my data as JSON encoded in UTF-8 with:

```
 json_file = fromJSON(d, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Then my code analyse the JSON and create a DataFrame.

Now i convert everything in UTF-8 with:

```
for (col in colnames(df)){
            Encoding(df[[col]]) <- "UTF-8"}
```

Now from RStudio I read "Belgi<eb>" but in my datatable on shinyproxy is rendered as "Belgi�" (it's should be België).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Turns out that België in not "*UTF-8*" but it's "*latin1*". So it is sufficient to encode it as "*latin1*".